# Tiny-CAN I-XL socketCAN extended format

Tags: linux, can-bus, socketcan, canutils

My Problem is the following. I am using the Tiny-CAN I-XL CAN-USB adapter and socketCAN on Linux.
I configure the CAN adapter by doing:

> sudo slcan_attach /dev/ttyUSB0 -w
>
> sudo ip link set can0 type can bitrate 100000 restart-ms 500
>
> sudo ifconfig can0 up

Same process with a second adapter (can1) and displaying both via candump in two terminals.

Sending standard messages is fine via:

> cansend can0 123#11.22.33.44.55.66.77.88

But using extended format does not work:

> cansend can0 12345678#11.22.33.44.55.66.77.88

What am I missing? Did I forget to do a specific setting?

I figured that Bit 31 of the CAN-id should be 1 as described in can.h to turn EFF on.
Therefore a message like:

> cansend can0 81111123#11.22.33.44.55.66.77.88

should work. but it doesn't.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Firmware update of the Tiny-CAN I-XL CAN-USB fixes this problem.